# How can I use 3DES securily in Java?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, java-7

As per NIST research 3DES is not a good cipher. But after lot of reading I understand the weakness is in implementation (using weak, semiweak and combination) but not in the specification.

We use Oracle JSSE/JCA (JDK 1.7). How can I validate the 3DES ciphers are weaker ones? Does enabling FIPS mode helps here?

Reference [NIST SP800-57 part 1: Recommendation for Key Management (part 1)](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-57/sp800-57_part1_rev3_general.pdf)

Comment: Use AES instead of 3DES if you have choice. 3DES is enough strong for middle level attacker.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the security of a cipher and not programming. The question may be better suited for [security.se] instead.

Comment: You're asking different questions in the question title and question body. Please choose one and stick with it. Hint: The title question is opinion-based and will be closed.

Comment: Substantially edited question to make it on topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIPS, as I understand, still allows TDEA to be used with 3 independent keys (3 key 3DES). Using 3DES with a single key is of course DES and DES has been insecure for some time. Using 2 key 3DES (DES-ABA) is now not FIPS compliant anymore either.

Unfortunately Java only supported 3 key 3DES (DES-ABC). That means that many developers simply copied the first DES key to be used as the third key when they were required to implement DES-ABA. The only way to detect such keys is to compare the first and the last key part of the 3DES key to each other.

To use 3DES in the most secure way, simply generate a 192 bit key using the "DESede" `KeyGenerator`.

```
KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DESede");
keyGen.init(168);
SecretKey desABCKey = keyGen.generateKey();
```

Note that this generates a 192 bit key where the 24 parity bits are correctly set (168 bits effective, giving you about 112 bits of security).

Setting FIPS mode won't help, as that only seems an option for the "Sun" JSSE provider that implements TLS. It *may* help if you have cryptgraphy providers from other vendors.

As for the distinction between weak and semi-weak: this probably relates to the keys used for the underlying DES block cipher. Generally you should not validate the keys themselves to be weak but rather the implementation. As long as the keys have sufficient entropy the likeliness of generating weak keys can be safely ignored.

---

You *should* be using AES as it is both more secure, faster, more future proof, has a larger block size, no weak keys, fully randomized keys (etc. etc. etc.).